# Multiple linear regression with categorical features using sklearn - python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, data-mining

I have a dataset, where each document possesses a corresponding score/ rating

```
dataset = [
   {"text":"I don't like this small device", "rating":"2"},
   {"text":"Really love this large device", "rating":"5"},
   ....
]
```

In addition, I have a category(variable) of term lists extracted out of `text` variables from the same dataset

```
x1 = [short, slim, small, shrink]
x2 = [big,huge,large]
```

So, how can I  do the linear regression with `multiple independent variables` as a word lists(**or varible representing the existence of any word from corresponding term list, because each term in lists is unique**  ) above and the `dependent variable as a rating`. In other words

> how could I evaluate term lists impact on the rating with sklearn

I used `TfidfVectorizer` to derive the document-term matrix. If it's possible please provide simple code snippet or example.

Comment: What is the relation between `x1` and `x2` and the values of `text`? There seems to be no overlap between the words.

Comment: Those word extracted from text variables (over 10.000 samples),  those word lists exists in text variables, @fuglede

Comment: So are you saying that in your regression, you want only those words to be taken into account? And if so, I take it you really want `x1 + x2` to appear as features?

Comment: Yep, but one list as one independent variable, Because each list has it's naming(category) like "big size", so I want to explore the impact of that categories on rating @fuglede

Comment: How will you boil down the lists to a variable? Can you provide a few examples of texts and their corresponding encodings?

Comment: What does x1(category) mean? Edit: The comment that this comment responded to has now been deleted, so this comment no longer makes much sense.

Comment: Also, note that assuming that your rating are on a fixed finite scale, linear regression will produce strange results: Not only will predictions not be integral, but they need not even be confined to the interval of interest. Given that the ratings come with a natural ordering, you will probably want to look into [ordinal regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression).

Comment: @fuglede So I thought that community would help me the arranging this question about encoding string list variable to use in regression. But so far I have documents term matrix of the text variables

Comment: Perhaps you want to associate to each text two binary variables whose values are given by whether or not they contain any words from each of the two lists, or something like that? (In which case you are going to get at most 4 different outputs of the model.)

Comment: @fuglede yes and make regression analysis, and as I understand so far x1 represent the existence of any word from the corresponding word list, right?

Comment: Yep, that's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the discussion in the comments, it seems that the interpretation should be that each list defines a binary variable whose value depends on whether or not any words from the list appear in the text in question. So, let us first change the texts so that the words actually appear:

```
dataset = [
   {"text": "I don't like this large device", "rating": "2"},
   {"text": "Really love this small device", "rating": "5"},
   {"text": "Some other text", "rating": "3"}
]
```

To simplify our work, we'll then load this data into a data frame, change the ratings to be integers, and create the relevant variables:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
df['rating'] = df['rating'].astype(int)
df['text'] = df['text'].str.split().apply(set)
x1 = ['short', 'slim', 'small', 'shrink']
x2 = ['big', 'huge', 'large']
df['x1'] =  df.text.apply(lambda x: x.intersection(x1)).astype(bool)
df['x2'] =  df.text.apply(lambda x: x.intersection(x2)).astype(bool)
```

That is, at this point `df` is the following data frame:

```
   rating                                   text     x1     x2
0       2  {this, large, don't, like, device, I}  False   True
1       5    {this, small, love, Really, device}   True  False
2       3                    {other, Some, text}  False  False
```

With this, we can create the relevant model, and check what the coefficients end up being:

```
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(df[['x1', 'x2']], df.rating)
print(model.coef_)  # array([ 2., -1.])
print(model.intercept_)  # 3.0
```

As also mentioned in the comments, this thing will produce at most four ratings, one for each of the combinations of `x1` and `x2` being `True` or `False`. In this case, it just so happens that all possible outputs are integers, but in general, they need not be, nor need they be confined to the interval of interest. Given the ordinal nature of the ratings, this is really a case for some sort of [ordinal regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression) (cf. e.g. [mord](https://pythonhosted.org/mord/)).

Comment: Thank you very  much, that is really helpful to my thesis project

Comment: You're welcome. If this is the answer you were looking for, you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: one more questions, since skleanr doesn't provide the summary for interpreting LinerRegression , how can I implement the same functionality with statsmodel in order to get a summary table?

Comment: `sm.OLS(df.rating, df[['x1', 'x2']].astype(int)).fit().summary()`